# Generic functions in Rust

Tags: generics, rust

I would like create shared library (plugin) with generic function.
**T** can be : u8, u16, u32, float, i8, i16, i32.

```
pub struct Api {}
    impl Api {
        pub fn write_to_slave<T>(&self, id: u32, value: T)
        {
            println!("write to slave id : {}, value: {}", id, value);
        }
    }
```

Error:

````
   |
18 |     pub fn write_to_slave<T>(&self, id: u32, value: T)
   |                           - help: consider restricting this bound: `T: std::fmt::Display`
19 |     {
20 |         println!("write to slave id : {}, value: {}", id, value);
   |                                                           ^^^^^ `T` cannot be formatted with the default formatter
   |
   = help: the trait std::fmt::Display is not implemented for T
   = note: in format strings you may be able to use {:?} (or {:#?} for pretty-print) instead
   = note: required by std::fmt::Display::fmt```
````

Comment: Have you tried what the error message suggests to do? It helpfully shows you the exact trait bound you need to include to make this code compile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the commenter mentioned. You need to specify a trait bound on your generic type T, see below. This requires that the type T implements the Display trait. [Here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/generics/bounds.html) is a link to the Rust docs for this topic.

```
pub struct Api {}
impl Api {
   pub fn write_to_slave<T: Display>(&self, id: u32, value: T)
      {
         println!("write to slave id : {}, value: {}", id, value);
      }
}
```